# if I use singin with these dns services, can someone still figure out where I am hosted?

Tags: domain-name-system

Normally if I go with a hosting company, I use their own dns.  so anyone who does a whois can figure out which company I am hosted with.

If I go with something like dnsmadeeasy etc., I use their dns servers.  can someone still figure out where I am hosted somehow?

Comment: Why would someone care who you're hosted with?

Comment: just curious that's all.

Answer (score 8):

It has to point to your host's IP address so of course they can.

If you're accessible from the internet, then someone can figure it out. There isn't much of a way around that.

Comment: but just an IP alone won't tell them I am hosting with abc hosting?

Comment: Sure it can, you just have to know how/where to look.

Comment: An IP address can certainly identify your hosting company. Two simple examples: `traceroute` will show the names of the routers in front of your server, which usually include your hosting provider’s name. `whois ip.ad.dr.ess` will give the owner of the IP address, usually the hosting provider.

Why do you need to “hide” this information?

Answer (score 3):

DNS just points at an IP address, regardless of whose nameservers you're using. IP addresses are traceable back to the ISP that ultimately owns them. There is no way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will, the DNS name will point at an IP, which in turn belongs to someone somewhere.

You can use various tools to track the location of an IP, for example DNSstuff have a pretty good [IP Whois tool](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools/ipall/?tool_id=67&token=&toolhandler_redirect=0&ip=8.8.8.8)

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking about Private domain registrations such as what [**GoDaddy Provides**](http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/dbp/landing.asp?isc=cjc749t2%3f&ci=9002).  DNS information is meant to be shared in order for people to be successfully forwarded to sites/services you want them to reach.  In order for people to reach you, they need to know one or two things: DNS name or an IP.

Through DNS, anyone can find information about who's hosting what for your domain, just do a quick DNS lookup or go to [**http://www.intodns.com/**](http://www.intodns.com/), and find a bunch of sweet DNS information about a domain.

IP owners can be found doing a quick WHOIS lookup since ARIN keeps a [**public database**](http://ws.arin.net/whois/) of every address it allocates.  They HAVE TO be able to provide administrative contact information.  There is no way to make this private.